# How did I get +15 points on this answer?

Tags: support

I got a notification for +15 points on one of my posts:

[image]

Clicking on that link brings me to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/what-are-the-tradeoffs-for-tall-vs-wide-empires-in-civilization-6/289109#289109) answer. What surprises me is that I got +15 points. My understanding is that upvotes on answers give +10 points, and downvotes give -2 (plus the answer has no downvotes). So how did I end up with +15?

Comment: The OP accepted your answer?

Comment: Remember that you can always check on the [reputation tab](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/86844/david-grinberg?tab=reputation) of your user profile to see a detailed breakdown of your rep score.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The asker of the question marked it as accepted. This gives you +15 reputation. Though marking your own answer on your own question does not, and marking someone else's answer to your question will give you +2 rep.

Comment: herpaderp totally forgot about that. Thanks